# Cursor randomly skips?

Tags: android, android-cursor

I'm using a cursor to read SMS records and it seems like it randomly skips rows. Sometimes it's a few rows, sometimes it's 100+ rows, here and there.

(I hard coded the "selection" just to get a batch.) When I run it the first time, I copied the results into excel. I run it a second time, *without* changing any of the code, and copy the results again into excel. When I compare the _id from the two runs, the two sets of results are different. I can't find any pattern rhyme or reason. Well frankly I'm not sure how to go about troubleshooting this. I did in it a batch originally because I was going to narrow the selection down, but now that it is all random, I don't know how else to find the cause. In one instance, I changed selection to pull a an _id that appeared to be missing, but the cursor returned that row so it does exist, the cursor just isn't reading or pulling it.

I searched, but haven't seen it as a known issue or anything. Any ideas how to troubleshoot further?

```
String selection = "_id > 0 AND _id < 2001";
String sortOrder = "_id ASC";
cursor = getApplication().getContentResolver().query(
         Telephony.Sms.CONTENT_URI,null, selection, null, sortOrder);

cursor.moveToFirst();
for(int i=0; i<cursor.getCount(); i++){
   Log.i("DBTESTING", "~" + i + "~" + cursor.getInt(0)); //col 0 = _id column
   cursor.moveToNext();
}
```

Comment: are you sure column 0 is _id?

Comment: @njzk2 Yes I'm sure, I logged the column name at different times during the project.

Comment: is that id supposed to be an int? is it possible that it would be a string instead, in which case the comparison would work a bit differently?